# mysql C connector functions not working when defined within a class

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11

I was trying to implement the functions in mysql c-connector from the class "Server" in my project. Here is how the class constructor looks like:
(DATABASE and SOCKET are #defined).

```
Server::Server(MYSQL& conn)
{
    mysql_init(&conn);
    mysql_real_connect(&conn,"localhost","username","passwd",DATABASE,0,SOCKET,0);
    if (mysql_real_connect(&conn,"localhost","santu","hello",DATABASE,0,SOCKET,0) == NULL) {
        cout << mysql_error(&conn) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Connected." << endl;
    }
}
```

When I try calling the class from "main.cpp" with the connection handle, it causes an error.

```
Cannot connect twice. Already connected.
```

but if the methods were written outside the class, it runs flawlessly. Basically, this works.

```
#include "Server.hxx"

MYSQL san;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    mysql_init(&san);
    mysql_real_connect(&san,"localhost","santu","hello", "test",0,"/tmp/mysql.sock",0);
    cout << mysql_error(&san) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't and fails with aforementioned error.

```
#include "Server.hxx"

MYSQL san;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Server S0(san);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class function definition you are calling `mysql_real_connect` twice:

```
mysql_real_connect(&conn,"localhost","username","passwd",DATABASE,0,SOCKET,0);
if (mysql_real_connect(&conn,"localhost","santu","hello",DATABASE,0,SOCKET,0) == NULL) {
```

Just remove the first line and it will work fine.

Comment: But why can't it ignore the second connection though ? previously, I couldn't execute mysql_close(&san). it gave me bus error. Could you please explain it ?

Comment: @Vasanth hard to say without looking at the internals of the MySQL API code, but I guess that's just not the way the interface is designed.